# How to reduce size of apk that have a lot of images

Tags: android, performance, android-image

I've my first app last week, but when I prepare to public it, I found a issue with my app. The apk file is too large (over 12Mb) because I have over 20 full HD images in drawable folder. Then I try to reduce resolution of images and the apk size reduced a bit. But I think it is not a good way. Please tell me how can I reduce size of apk without decrease resolution of images.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use this [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/). It help to reduce the size of Image without decrease image quality.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of issues, you have to compress your images in some sites and again putting all the compress image to your folder, it will reduce the size of the APK for sure.

I have done the same for my long project has so many images and lastly the APK file made of 80MB, the same I have implemented to my project which I reduced the APK file from 80 MB to 40 MB.

Hope this works fine for you. Any help needed, do let me know.

Comment: Are there anyway to use image without compress but don't make apk size too large ?

Comment: No, just because if your APK size is more than enough, it's not working anymore. For that you need to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept to lose image-quality, you will make your application to be smaller. And, [CompressNow](http://compressnow.com/) can help to reduce the size of image without decrease image quality.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is an old question so just putting it out there.

You can convert PNG, JPEG or BMP images in your project to WebP which in most cases take lesser space. *If the min version is 18 and above, then you can go for a lossless conversion as well.*

There is a new tool in Android Studio to convert images to WebP.
Right click on any image or even on 'res' folder itself -> click on "Convert to WebP".

For more information on this tool refer:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/webp